# How to Organize the classes of a low level design in code blocks IDE

Tags: oop, c++11, codeblocks, low-level-code

I am having an interview where I have to do low level design coding in an IDE which I have choosed to do in code blocks IDE .
So I have question of how to organize different classes of that design. My point of asking is if I have 10 classes  should I create all 10 different classes in a project by adding every time a new class. I think it would be bad approach.
So Is there any other approach to do so.

Comment: could you give an example to explain what you mean by "low level design coding"?

Answer (score 0):

If, in the program you're developing, classes interact with each other, they must to be in the same project. 
in a single project, you can and must have all the classes you need to instantiate the objects what you need in the program.